# How to post earned score like in Google's Doodle games?

Tags: google-plus, posting, google-doodle

I am going to host a simple HTML/JS game on my personal site and would like to give players an ability to post their score into Google Plus like in Doodles:

[image]

But I don't even know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as an [interactive post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive).

The general idea is that you would provide a button or link that says "share your score" or something similar. This would bring up the interactive post that you have described above. That interactive post would contain a link to a page containing the user's score as part of the text and the image to display (so Google's bot can scrape that info), and could contain some pre-filled text for the user to edit or accept and a "call to action" button encouraging people to play the game.

For example, your button might look something like this:

```
<button
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="https://example.com/userScore?gameid=123456789"
  data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="I had fun with this game! You can play it too!"
  data-calltoactionlabel="PLAY"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://example.com/playGame">
  Share your score
</button>
```

You need to use the [developer console](http://console.developers.google.com/) to get a clientid for this webapp if you don't already have one. The page also needs this boilerplate text just before the closing  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>
```

See the page on [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) for details.

You would also need a userScore page that contained [snippet markup](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) with the relevant game information for this specific game.

Comment: So I edit on the fly (because it would make debugging a thing, unknown to me, even harder) my `http://example.com/`, place the button, set two attribute urls to the same frontpage, put generated (and allowed to accept requests from `http://*.example.com/*`) API Key instead of xxxxx, execute code -- it spawns two iframes. I click the button and get: `401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

Bad request.`

Answer (score -1):

According to [this official source](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive), Google plus dont let you do that.

You even can try to use the `schema.org` like that

```
?redirect_url=http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com&img=YOUR-IMAGE.jpg&description=YOUR-SCORE&title=YOUR-GAME
```